# how to install dot net framework 4.5 on amd64 ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, .net-framework, wine, winetricks

I've tried simple plain installation. It shows error:

```
wine: Call from 0x7b8395fc to unimplemented function wevtapi.dll.EvtNext, aborting
```

Wine version:

```
wine --version
wine-1.6.2
```

When installing with winetricks it installs 2.0 version of the framework first, then 3.0 version, after that it shows that 4.5 version conflicts with 3.0 and aborts installation.

Comment: Does Mono not solve your issues?